# Database forms VS Programming

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleforms

What is the benefit of using Oracle Database forms VS using C#(VB) or like this for programming? from academic view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a flexibility vs speed of development comparison. The forms package will be less flexible I would have thought but the barrier to entry for someone who doesn't programming is probably lower. Depends what you need. If its simply a learning exercise then a forms approach to explain generating a UI from a DB should be fine. You can lead to how to program a more complex GUI from the DB using a programming language such as C#

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is that C#(VB) are more general purpose while Oracle Forms has a much smaller domain.  So if you are writing an Oracle database driven application for a well defined user population (not a public internet application), Oracle Forms can speed up development even without learning being a major factor for the developer.  One large advantage that C#(VB) would have is that there is a lot more development done in those environments so there are more resources (examples, libraries, etc.).